# Using Python to automate creation of JIRA tickets

Tags: python, exception, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I have been trying to write a python script to automatically raise Jira tickets, and have been running into some trouble. To be more specific, I tried to use both the issue_create and create_issue methods as outlined in the [atlassian-python API reference](https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/jira.html#manage-issues). In the code provided below, I successfully obtain the correct project id just to verify that my authentication (PAT) works. However the second part fails and a Jira ticket (task) is not created.

For reference, here is my code:

```
from atlassian import Jira

jira = Jira(
    url   = "https://jira.example.com/",
    token = "MyPersonalAccessToken"
)

proj = jira.get_project('key', expand=None)
print(proj.get("id")) # to verify that authentication worked


jira = Jira(
    url   = "https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue",
    token = "MyPersonalAccessToken"
)

jira.issue_create(
    fields={
        'project': {
            'key': 'key' 
        },
        'summary': 'Testing JIRA python API',
        'description': 'testing',
        'issuetype': {
            "name": "Task"
        },
    }
)
```

Below is the output I get when running the code above:

```
<PROJECT ID>
Creating issue "Testing JIRA python API"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<user>/jira_python/jira.py", line 21, in <module>
    jira.issue_create(
  File "/Users/<user>/.local/share/virtualenvs/new_project-RFzzfWjC/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/jira.py", line 1435, in issue_create
    return self.post(url, data={"fields": fields})
  File "/Users/<user>/.local/share/virtualenvs/new_project-RFzzfWjC/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 333, in post
    response = self.request(
  File "/Users/<user>/.local/share/virtualenvs/new_project-RFzzfWjC/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 257, in request
    self.raise_for_status(response)
  File "/Users/<user>/.local/share/virtualenvs/new_project-RFzzfWjC/lib/python3.10/site-packages/atlassian/rest_client.py", line 490, in raise_for_status
    raise HTTPError(error_msg, response=response)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError
```

I should also note that I have tried using just the base URL (jira.example.com) but I also received the same error. Please note that in the above code, the url and token have been modified for obvious reasons. I've tried using try-except to catch the error but to no avail.

How can I find out where I'm going wrong and why my issues are not being created?

Please let me know if I should provide further information, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you get more details about the error by excepting it and printing? `except HTTPError as e: print(e.response.text)`

Comment: @matszwecja This is what I get: 

```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<user>/jira_python/jira.py", line 33, in <module>
    except HTTPError as e:
NameError: name 'HTTPError' is not defined. Did you mean: 'TabError'?```

Comment: You need to add that error to namespace by importing it from request first...

Comment: As it turns out, I was missing a mandatory field in the payload (fields) and the url I was using in the issue_create call was incorrect, but using the exception + print helped me catch it. I just wasn't handling the exception properly before. If you'd like, you can post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as the solution. Thank you for the help @matszwecja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to provide an answer here, for which I want to provide most of the credit to @matszwecja who hinted how to properly raise an exception so I can find out what's going on.

---

After adding an exception handler, I was able to catch the two issues that were preventing my script from working as intended:

The url parameter in the issue_create call should be "https://jira.example.com" instead of "https://jira.example.com/rest/api/2/issue", the issue_create function adds the correct endpoint automatically.

I was missing a mandatory custom field, which was specific to my Jira project settings. Using an exception handler helped me find that out. See the code that worked below:

```
from atlassian import Jira
from requests import HTTPError

jira = Jira(
    url   = "https://jira.example.com/",
    token = "MyPersonalAccessToken"
)
try:

    jira.issue_create(
        fields={
            'project': {
                'key': 'key' 
            },
            'summary': 'Testing JIRA python API',
            'description': 'testing',
            'issuetype': {
                "name": "Task"
            },
    
        }
    )
except HTTPError as e:
    print(e.response.text)
```

I hope this helps anyone who may run into similar issues.

Comment: Printing out the exception text really helped; as in "HTTPError as e: print(e.response.text)"